# dataframe from 2 classes beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I want to extract Arbeitsatmosphare rank and Stadt information based on review data from below website for ALL pages, so desired output should be as in example below

```
         Arbeitsatmosphare | Stadt
   1.      4.00            | Berlin     
   2.      5.00            | Frankfurt
   3.      3.00            | Munich
   4.      5.00            | Berlin
   5.      4.00            | Berlin
```

Below code extracts pro data from website from all pages and works fine. I tried to update it and to add 2 lists, Arbeitsatmosphare rank and Stadt in it and break cycle if Arbeitsatmosphare rank info is missing, but my code is not working. Can you help?

```
pro = []

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    page = 1
    while True:
        print(f"Processing page {page}..")
        url = f'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/{page}'
        response = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        new_comments = [
            pro.find_next_sibling('p').get_text()
            for pro in soup.find_all('h2', text='Pro')
        ]
        if not new_comments:
            print(f"No more comments. Page: {page}")
            break
        pro += new_comments
        print(pro)
        #print(len(pro))
        page += 1
print(pro)
```

UPD
Adding my code that is not working, however I think that there should be more simple solution

```
Arbeit = []
Stadt=[]

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    page = 1
    while True:
        print(f"Processing page {page}..")
        url = f'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/{page}'
        response = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        new_comments1 = [
            Arbeit.find_next_sibling('span').get_text()
            for Arbeit in soup.find_all('span', text='Arbeitsatmosphäre')
        ]
        new_comments2 = [
            Stadt.find_next_sibling('div').get_text()
            for Stadt in soup.find_all('div', text='Stadt')
        ]
        if not new_comments1:
            print(f"No more comments. Page: {page}")
            break
        Arbeit += new_comments1
        Stadt += new_comments2
        print(Arbeit)
        print(Stadt)
        #print(len(pro))
        page += 1
```

Comment: From what I understand, the code you've posted works for you but you've updated the code but it now isn't working. Could you post the new code so we can see where the problem might be?

Comment: UPD Adding my code that is not working, however I think that there should be more simple solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as  pd

arbeit = []
firma = []
stadt = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    page = 1
    while True:
        print(f"Processing page {page}..")
        url = f'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/{page}'
        response = session.get(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        articles = soup.find_all('article')
        print("Number of articles: " + str(len(articles)))
        for article in articles:
            rating_tags = article.find_all('span', {'class' : 'rating-badge'})            
            arbeit.append(rating_tags[0].text.strip())
            detail_div = article.find_all('div', {'class' : 'review-details'})[0]
            nodes = detail_div.find_all('li')
            firma_node = nodes[0]
            stadt_node = nodes[1]
            firma_node_div = firma_node.find_all('div')
            firma_name = firma_node_div[1].text.strip()
            firma.append(firma_name)

            stadt_node_div = stadt_node.find_all('div')
            stadt_name = stadt_node_div[1].text.strip()
            stadt.append(stadt_name)                                       
        page += 1

        pagination = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'paginationControl'})
        if not pagination:
            break

df = pd.DataFrame({'Arbeitsatmosphäre' : arbeit, 'Stadt' : stadt})
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you. But the cycle endlessly ranning. Probably that because of infinite number of pages (if you type in url  page/10000, you see that it exists). For example if we change url to Audi https://www.kununu.com/de/audi-zentrum/kommentare where only 9 comments, cycle still will be extracting data from infinite pages...

Comment: check now. added code to check if `pagination` div is present or not.

Comment: check now. there was a typo. it should have been `soup`instead of `article`